# Data streaming using MongoOperations

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using spring data mongoOperations to issue queries against mongoDb and my result result set contains large set of documents. These can't be written all at once in to the local memory to avoid memory hog.
I checked MongoOperations API and it does have a stream method. Not sure if this stream method is a wrapper on top of Mongo Cursors or something in sync with Java 8 stream support.
What would be the best way to stream data using mongoTemplate and not write all the documents at once in to the memory ?

Answer (score 0):

The `mongoOperations.stream(...)` method returns an Iterator. Use `StreamUtils.createStreamFromIterator`. With a static import it's concise and works fine:

```
import static org.springframework.data.util.StreamUtils.createStreamFromIterator;
//
createStreamFromIterator(mongoOperations.stream(query, SomeEntity.class)).
                map(SomeEntity::getFirstName). ...
```